# Get HTML data and append to a .txt file in server with PHP

Tags: php, html, server, frontend, backend

I have been trying to get the data input from `<teaxtarea>` and append it in a .txt file in the server everytime someone inputs there. The server-side language is currently PHP. I have been trying for a possible solution online or in the tutorials, but likely end up with unsatisfied result. I am pretty sure it's a really simple thing, but as a total newbie (just started PHP few days ago) I am really lost right now.

Help will be much appreciated.

I have tried so many methods, now a bit lost. Here's something I have tried and failed. -

```html
<?php
  
  $myfile = "input.txt";
  $txt = $_POST["text"];
  fopen($myfile, "a");
  fwrite($myfile, $txt);
  fclose($myfile);

  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
   <body>
   
      <form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "POST">
      <textarea name="text"></textarea>
         <input type="submit"></input>
      </form>
   
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: "I have been trying" — Then show us a [mcve]. There's no point in writing [another tutorial](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+write+file&t=hf&ia=web)

Comment: We'd like to see what you've done to be able to help.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Comment: The file gets created, but no data gets appended/written in the .txt file.

Comment: I believe the question isn't appropriate enough for anyone to understand what was asked. Where it's getting confusing exactly? Can someone tell me? So that I can improve it for the better.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to the documentation for `fopen` and `fwrite`.

`fopen` will return a file pointer which you will need to pass to any functions like `fwrite` and `fclose`. Passing the file name will not work.

Also, using "a" in fopen requires the file to exist. Change it to "a+" to create it if needed and make sure the script has permission to do so.

Finally, if you want new form submissions to go on a new line, you will need to add new line yourself because "a" will put the file pointer to the end of the file only. It will not add newlines for you.

This should work:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["text"])) {
  $txt = $_POST["text"];
  $fp = fopen("text.txt", "a+");
  fwrite($fp, $txt . PHP_EOL);
  fclose($fp);
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <form method = "POST">
          <textarea name="text"></textarea>
          <input type="submit"></input>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

As an alternative to the `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fclose` combo, you could also just use

```
file_put_contents("text.txt", $_POST["text"] . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I had got it wrong. 
I have edited it to this - 
`$myfile = fopen("input.txt", "a");` and it seems to be working and appending data as expected.

That alnighter just costed me 12 rep, but alright, need to sacrfice to move forward I guess.

Comment: Doesn't work this code, please try to publish full example or edit current one!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is wrong.

You could leave it blank, because the target php-code is on the same page, or use

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

And like Gordon said, you have to define a file, e.g.

```
$filePath = './file/path.txt';
$file = fopen($filePath, 'a');
frwite($file, $message);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the action of mine seems to be working though.